# Problem using redux-thunk to connect an abstract class with Redux state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-thunk

This is the basic pattern that I use with `redux-thunk` and class components in React. The below code exports a class definition `MyClass` which is properly connected with the state brought in by `mapStateToProps` and has access to the actions defined in `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

type OwnProps = ... // whatever
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, ownProps: OwnProps) => { return ... }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch)=>{ return ... }

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

type Props = PropsFromRedux & OwnProps; 
type LocalState = ... // whatever


class MyClass___ extends React.PureComponent<Props, LocalState>

export const MyClass = connector(MyClass___)
```

However, the above pattern fails when I am trying to define a base abstract class that concentrates certain functionalities that are used all over the place and that it, too, needs to be connected to Redux. If the class `MyClass___` is abstract I get the following error on the final line:

```
Argument of type 'typeof MyClass___' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
Type 'typeof MyClass___' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

Answer (score 1):

Several observations here:

- Today you should be writing React components as *function* components, not classes. Classes still work, but they're effectively deprecated.  The in-progress React docs rewrite at https://beta.reactjs.org only teaches function components, new features like hooks only work with function components, and they're the way the React team *wants* people writing components.

  - Related to that, even if you *are* using class components, [the React team has advised *against* using class inheritance with React at all](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).  Instead you should be using component composition to reuse functionality.
- Similarly, the Redux team (myself and Lenz Weber) specifically recommends using [the React-Redux hooks API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) rather than the legacy `connect` API.  The hooks API is much simpler to use in general, *and* it is *vastly* easier to use with TypeScript.

Please see our recommended patterns for using Redux and TypeScript here:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start